# Using require.js for c3 CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, c3.js

I'm trying to use require and configure my path for c3.js CDN but I continue to get a script error.
Here is my code so far:

```
<script>
      require.config({

    "paths": {
        "d3": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3",
        "c3": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3"
    }

    }
);
</script>

<script>
require(['d3', 'c3'], function(d3, c3) {

    console.log(d3);
    console.log(c3);

});
</script>
```

The errors I'm getting are:

1. GET https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3-min.js?version=20151112172347
2. Uncaught Error: Script error for: c3

Comment: The URL in the configuration you show does not correspond to the URL in `GET` error you show.

Comment: not really sure why that error is happening then. I'm doing this through SAP Design Studio and only d3 is included in their sdk. I changed the d3 path to their source and I'm still getting the same error.